# unable to access child component $refs inside b-modal

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I am attempting to access a child component's $refs inside a b-modal.

On page load, I can see with vue dev tools that "agent-edit" has not been created. If I put the component outside of b-modal, it does show and I can access it --  however I need this to load inside a modal. How can I access $refs.editAgent? Can I force this child component to load with the page?

```
<b-modal id="editModal" ref="editModal" title="Edit Agent" size="lg">
    <agent-edit ref="editAgent"></agent-edit>
    <div slot="modal-footer" class="w-100"></div>
</b-modal>
```

Answer (score 3):

Refs are relative to the component they are created in (not the child components)

```js
// use this
this.$refs.editAgent

// Not this
this.$refs.editModal.$refs.editAgent
```

Note that `b-modal` is `lazy` by default, meaning the content is not rendered (instantiated) in the document until the modal is shown.

Once the modal is finished opening, you should have access to the refs (they don't exist until they are rendered into the DOM)

Listen for the modal's `shown` event, and then access the refs once that event is emitted.

Comment: is there a way to force that b-modal to be not-lazy -- the issue is that the error keeps getting thrown no matter how i try to ref it, i did attempt this method as well

Comment: Use the `static` prop on `<b-modal>`. https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/modal#lazy-loading-and-static-modals

Comment: its on {} empty on refs .

Answer (score 1):

I guess, that there is no `<agent-edit>` inside `<b-modal>`, when you try to call the method.

When the modal is hidden, there is no need to render the child components. Try to first show the modal and *then* access its children (maybe even with a `Vue.$nextTick` to make sure everything is finished).

Answer (score 0):

In your case, `this.$refs.editModal.$refs.editAgent` should work.

But pay attemption to the use of *$refs* and think about [emitting events](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Listening-to-Child-Components-Events).

Comment: I still get "Cannot read property 'setEditAgent' of undefined" -- from parent I'm attempting to access child method: 

edit(agent, index) {
                this.$refs.editModal.$refs.editAgent.setEditAgent(agent);
                this.$refs['editModal'].show();
            }

Comment: what about your console.logs? Can you post them here?

Comment: vue.common.dev.js?4650:630 [Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'setEditAgent' of undefined"

found in

---> <BLink>
       <VueChunks> at /Users/cuimingda/Projects/vue-chunks/src/vue-chunks.vue
         <AgentsList> at resources/assets/js/adminComponents/components/vReportTable/agentsList.vue
           <Root>